# Use {{COL_FIELD}} in UI-Grid cellTemplate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to use COL_FIELD value in UI-grid cell template.

Basically what I'm trying to do, is to set a color for each cell based on its value in 'dateColor' dictionary.

The code looks like that:

```
function getMyServersTableFields(fieldsToShow,dateColor) {

            var specificColumnDef = [];

            _.each(fieldsToShow, function (item) {

                    specificColumnDef.push(
                        {
                            name: 'item',
                            displayName:'item',
                            cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-contents',
                            cellTooltip: true,
                            cellTemplate: '<div><strong style="color: ' + dateColor[ {{COL_FIELD}} ] + '"">{{COL_FIELD}}</strong></div>',
                            minWidth: 150,
                            aggregationType: function (items) {
                                return 'Total servers: ' + $filter('number')(items.length);
                            }
                        }
                    );
            }   

    }
```

As you can see 'dateColor' is a dictionary, and the way I'm trying to set color is by getting the value of `{{COL_FIELD}}` in that dictionary, but I can't manage to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is COL_FIELD? Is it possible you copy-pasted a snippet and should replace COL_FIELD with a column (item) field?

Comment: I think your cellTemplate string is wrong; you're using dateColor[..] outside the actual template, so it can/will never be evaluated. It should be moved to wihtin the string-quotes, but I am pretty sure accessing the dateColor dictionary will no longer work.
Have you considered using css and classes to change colors?

Answer (score 1):

Your cellTemplate definition is wrong.
The COL_FIELD needs to be inside the string definition, COL_FIELD outside the string doesn't exist.

You can do it like this:

```
function getMyServersTableFields(fieldsToShow, dateColor) {
var specificColumnDef = [];
_.each(fieldsToShow, function (item) {
    specificColumnDef.push({
        name: 'item',
        displayName: 'item',
        cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-contents',
        cellTooltip: true,
        //cellTemplate: '<div><strong style="color: ' + dateColor[ {{COL_FIELD}} ] + '"">{{COL_FIELD}}</strong></div>',
        cellTemplate: '<div><strong ng-style="{\'color\': col.colDef.dateColor[COL_FIELD]}">{{COL_FIELD}}</strong></div>',
        dateColor: dateColor,
        minWidth: 150,
        aggregationType: function (items) {
            return 'Total servers: ' + $filter('number')(items.length);
        }
        })
    })
}
```

I also changed the style to ng-style since you're using interpolation to set the style.